# ElasticSearch or Criteria API for a listing website

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, filter, criteria-api

We are currently developing a Spring boot app, kinda like a listing website with a filter based on around 20-25 columns. The columns don't contain large text inside, most of them are numbers and some are enums, one is a list of strings which is persisted in another extra table with ID of the other row and the string.

The query is basically number > and < checks && string equality

The table from which the filter searches is expected to have around 100-150 thousand rows one at a time, because we delete old records when not needed.

We are using MYSQL for database.

Our current implementation is using CRITERIA API, but we still haven't done a performance test to see if it works good enough or not with a lot of records.

Since later it will be hard to change everything to elastic search, I wanted to see peoples opinion if we should change the implementation to elastic search.